# Javascript regex doesn't get validated on my site, but it does on validators

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm literally hitting my head on the wall.
I have this regex pattern

```
(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube.com\/(?:watch\?.*\bv=|embed\/|v\/)|ytimg\.com\/vi\/)(.+?)(?:[^-a-zA-Z0-9]|$)
```

which extracts off the id of a youtube video. I tried it here

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

with any subject string, let's say http://youtube.com/watch?v=21312321 and it works.

However on my site, I have the following input field

```
<input type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="Post a youtube video link">
```

and the following jquery code

```
$('#status').keyup(function(event){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var pattern = "(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube.com\/(?:watch\?.*\bv=|embed\/|v\/)|ytimg\.com\/vi\/)(.+?)(?:[^-a-zA-Z0-9]|$)";
    var re = new RegExp(pattern);
      if (value.match(re)) {
        console.log("Successful match");
      } else {
        console.log("No match");
      }     
});
```

and by using the same video as above, the result is "No match". 
How is that even possible, please tell my what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression literal instead:

```
var re = /(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube.com\/(?:watch\?.*\bv=|embed\/|v\/)|ytimg\.com\/vi\/)(.+?)(?:[^-a-zA-Z0-9]|$)/;
```

What’s happening is that a string already “evaluates” escapes, so your `\.` and `\b` are becoming `.` and the backspace character. `new RegExp` is the wrong function to use most of the time, and is only really useful when you have a dynamic regular expression (which is also wrong most of the time) — regular expression literals are more efficient, easier to read and therefore less error-prone.

(Also, `youtube.com` should probably be `youtube\.com`.)

Comment: Yes this does work and yes for some reason I overlooked the dot after youtube, but can you explain me why it worked on the validator site and not locally, although it used the same code?

Comment: @Systemfreak: He did explain it, and it's *not* quite the same code.  Your `\.` sequences were being interpreted as escape sequences when placed into a string.  You need to escape every `\ ` character.  `var pattern = "(?:youtu\\.be\\/..."`.

Comment: @Systemfreak: Do you mean because the validator site uses `new RegExp`? The problem isn’t in `new RegExp` itself; it’s in the string. When you type a string into a textbox and a script gets its value, nothing changes. But what’s between the quotes in a string literal doesn’t necessarily match what its value is, because strings have escape sequences using ``\``.